# jquery Ajax call resulting in Undefined Error in Firefox

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, firefox

I've been pulling my hair out for the last few hours with this problem. And the googling has been hampered by the very vagueness of this. So let me apologise for that first.

Basically I'm using jquery and ajax (with C#) to return data from the backend and display that to the screen. The code works perfectly for firefox and IE. But when the data gets too large (??) (1500+ table rows) all I get is an undefined popup.

Debugging in firefox (3.6) it doesn't even go into the success method. Worse still it doesn't even go into the error method. A lot of superfluous information there, but I'd rather show everything I'm doing.

The Code

```
$j.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "AdminDetails.aspx/LoadCallDetails",
            data: "{" + data + "}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",                
            success: function(msg) {
                $j("#CallDetailsHolder").html(msg.d);
                $j(".pointingHand").hide(); 

                var oTable = $j('#dt').dataTable({
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bPaginate": true,
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "sType": 'html' },
                        { "sType": 'custdate' },
                       { "sType": 'html-numeric' },
                        { "sType": 'ariary' },
                        { "sType": 'html' },
                        { "sType": 'html' }
                    ],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sProcessing": "Traitement...",
                        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Montrer",
                        "sZeroRecords": "Aucun enregistrement",
                        "sInfo": "_START_ à _END_ de _TOTAL_",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "0 à 0 de 0",
                        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrée à partir de _MAX_ )",
                        "sInfoPostFix": "",
                        "sSearch": "Rechercher",
                        "sUrl": "",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst": "premier",
                            "sPrevious": "Précédent",
                            "sNext": "suivant",
                            "sLast": "dernier"
                        }
                    },
                    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip'

                });

                $j('#CompteBlocRight0').unblock();

                $j('#btnRangeSearch').click(function() { oTable.fnDraw(); });

            },
            error: function(msg) {
                DisplayError(msg);
                $j('#CompteBlocRight0').unblock();
            }
        });               //$.ajax 
    }
```

The code definitely works. And even displays in IE without any issues.

Any help???

Comment: Have you used FireBug to help debug what is going on?

Comment: Yes, it hits the error function, steps through some of the jQuery1.4.1 file quite a bit. But then doesn't even hit my DisplayError method which I find strange.

Comment: Can you tell if the data is returned correctly from the server? With FireBug you should be able to look at what comes back regardless of what the javascript does with it.

Comment: it never gets into the success method. when i hit step into, it goes to the error method definition. the html from the server side is correct.

Comment: You are returning JSON from the server to the browser, correct? What data is passed into the error method?

Comment: Just a personal note to explain inactivity on this question. I've had to flown off site after a serious bite of some kind (the bugs just won't leave us alone). Will get back to it once I recover (or some kind college whiz kid has sorted it out :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging, this seems to be the problem.

[Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=450633)

Answer (score 0):

Since it works with small datasets, and fails with large datasets, you need to isolate a failing case with a large dataset.

Use the Net tab in Firebug to see the server's response. Status 2xx should go into the success handler, all others should go into the error handler. Perhaps your server is puking in a way that the Ajax control gets confused?

With these sorts of errors, it's often *very* helpful to simplify your code for debugging. Try this code, with the handlers replaced with simple messages:

```
$j.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "AdminDetails.aspx/LoadCallDetails",
        data: "{" + data + "}",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",                
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log("in success handler");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("in error handler: "+textStatus);
            console.dir(xhr);
            console.dir(errorThrown);
        }
    });               //$.ajax 
}
```

**UPDATE:** the signature of your error handler is not correct. Updated my sample.

Comment: BTW, your server should be returning JSON. You mentioned "html"...it's not returning HTML, is it? Cuz that could be the problem.

Comment: i've just checked, 200 OK returned. i'm only interested in the first field in the error method. i've noticed this works fine as an overload.

Comment: You're getting a 200 but the error method is still getting called?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the `200 OK` comes with `text/html` instead of `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your charset to utf-8? Could the keyword that triggers a big popup be something that the server side doesn't understand?

This article is about JSON/Ajax/UTF-8 using PHP, but have a read: http://particletree.com/notebook/json-ajax-and-utf8/

Comment: I doubt it. It's all numerics that are being passed in this case. Also that wouldn't explain why it works for smaller values. The numbers being passed are number of months and number of days so will always fall between 1-12 and 1-31 respectively. Confirmed correct on fail as well. Also note that when debugging the call completes correctly on the server and I can see the correct data in the result.